# mysql for payment system?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nosql

I'm trying to create a payment system for my website. The website is a market place for 3d printing blueprint. Users buy credits on my website. When a user purchase a 3d printing blueprint uploaded by other user, it creates a new tuple or a row in the 'purchased' table while deducting credit in user credit table. Here's the important part. My gut tells me to use event scheduler to mark rows of purchased as payed every month and wire the sum of money earned by each seller. My worry is the table will grow infinitely as months pass by.

- Is this the right implementation?
- Or can I somehow create a new table each month that holds transactions for only this month?
- Is there a Nosql equivalent to this?

Comment: One of the approaches is too create `archive` table and keep just recent month(s) in the current table.

Answer (score 3):

Stripe.com or Braintree.com might be good options for you.

It is not advisable to create or roll your own payments implementation. These established services not only handle the PCI compliance aspect of payments, but they also have direct support for the use case you're asking about.

In an effort to answer your question further - it's probably not going to be an issue from the stand point of performing inserts into this MySQL table or in terms of iterating across it for batch processing. Querying on the other hand will become more onerous as the data set gets very large.

You can use partitioning in MySQL and perform the partitioning based on date but I doubt this is something you should spend your time accomplishing at this point. Wait until your site blows up and is super popular then come back and update your schema and configuration to meet your actual usage demands.

It's worth noting that you'll also want to make sure to take regular backups of something as important of payments information. Typically you'd also see at least one replica for something this critical.

Again I don't think you should try and solve this yourself. Just pay for a service that does this for you and focus on building the best 3d blueprint marketplace.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the question. OP is asking how to store information about payments, not how to process credit cards.

Comment: Agree that the OP is asking how to store information about payments. One of the three questions in his list was "Is this a the right implementation?" and it was to this that I was trying to answer  "no". The OP is clearly looking for an easy way to handle payments so he can focus on his 3d blueprint site, making it relevant to offload payments work to existing providers. (At least that's what I meant to convey.)

Comment: It's okay. Any type of answers are welcomed! I learned something new related to the question I'm asking. Thank you.

Comment: However, I just checked with both braintree and stripe, and found out that they cannot provide a service for my use case where users purchase credits from my website and have my website pay out each sellers of their cumulative sales at the end of each month. Is there anyone who can answer in implementation perspective?

Comment: @noobie how do you plan to allow users to buy credits? How do you want them to redeem these credits? When they redeem them, will an ACH need to be sent to their bank account? Will you just Venmo them the money? Will you refund it to their CC? (And by redeem I mean how does the seller of a 3d blueprint convert the credits he receives into actual currency?)

Comment: A user will purchase a store credit among preset values such as $5, $10, and $20 etc using credit/debit card. At this point, I received the payment to my business bank account. Once a user buys an item posted by seller. The store credit get deducted, and new row for payment table will be created. At the end of each month, I will sum total sales for each sellers, and pay the seller using paypal from my bank account. I don't know whether I would need the transaction functionality of Mysql or just creating new tuple and updating table is sufficient enough.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay reply. Looking around on google, I found this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts which will provide you a managed way for actually making the 'payouts' to your users. You'll definitely want to use transactions when performing these operations although if you're using Paypal, you should consider that the authoritative source of truth, and you should only update your database when the PayPal payments API provides a confirmative response code. Any other questions about this topic? Nosql is probably not indicated at this point.